# How can I convert this vertices or render them?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

So let's say I have a list of 8 vertices to draw a cube. but for using the method `Gl.DrawElements(beginMode.quads)` to draw a cube, i need 24, 4 for each face. i have two questions.

1. Can I somehow convert these 8 vertices to 24 using some kind of trick? It also needs to be able to convert any 3D vertices to the desired number.
2. How can I draw using those 8 vertices?

Comment: You might read more about you want to do. You could start here: [Rotation of a Cube with OpenGL in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/adde9d/rotation-of-a-cube-with-opengl-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: Unless you know how these 8 points have to be connected, there is no way to automatically construct triangles (or an index buffer).